# Ubuntu 20 suddenly halts

Tags: 20.04

I have **a long-standing annoying issue**, so any help is extremely appreciated:

my laptop (HP ProBook 450 G3) powered by Ubuntu 20.04, randomly halts from time to time. Looking into syslog, I can see a sign of a hardware failure at the time of halt:

```
b 18 14:11:35 homik /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1635]: (II) event4  - PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device is a pointer
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Feb 18 14:53:48 homik systemd-modules-load[271]: Inserted module 'lp'
```

Some log entries right before the failure and system information can be found here - https://gist.github.com/Olena-Stotska/341a3ffe91529bc1c20ae5396d9135c3

There are constant symptoms of this failure, touchpad stops responding, short screen freezes, and in a few minutes system goes down.

### What have I tried?

This started to happen when I was on Ubuntu 16. So, I did:

1. Upgraded to Ubuntu 18 (same issue)
2. Upgraded to Ubuntu 20 (same issue)
3. Upgraded RAM to 32Gb (no effect)
4. Switched to SSD (no effect)
5. Self-monitoring of the laptop using metric beats and ELK (found nothing special in system state right before failure)
6. Self-minoring of the temperature of the system with lm-sensors with ElasticSearch (max temperature was not high enough to cause system halt). **however there is one sensor `acpitz-acpi-0: Adapter: ACPI interface` that reports 127C with max of 128C max**
7. Replaced battery with a more powerful one. I can use the laptop without a power supply for about 10 hours. So, the issue was not in the battery.
8. Ran stress tests using GTKStressTesting (https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/01/new-stress-test-linux-app). Didn't cause laptop halt

If I can provide anything else to help investigate the issue further, let me know.

### Update

**Done**:

- Updated BIOS to N78 Ver. 01.51
- [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) passed without any error:
  (added photo with results as a comment to gist: https://gist.github.com/Olena-Stotska/341a3ffe91529bc1c20ae5396d9135c3#gistcomment-3637994)
- had a crash with wayland (logs: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5HFW3rFHxX/)
- reset BIOS to system defaults

**Additional details**:
Very likely the issue is in the south bridge because symptoms are very close [described in this article](https://lickeys.ru/en/odnoklassniki/yuzhnyi-most-sgorel-simptomy-prichiny-remont-vyshel-iz-stroya/)

Comment: Maybe a silly question how old is the laptop?

Comment: Do you have an external mouse connected? Other USB devices? How is your mouse connected? USB, serial, other? Temporarily disconnect it and use the trackpad, and see if the problem is any better. Also, edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I updated github gist. Added requested details at the end of the 1st file. Nothing is connected. I use a touchpad only. Previously, I used bluetooth mouth

Comment: @David I bought it ~5 years ago \o/

Answer (score 2):

**BIOS**

HP ProBook 450 G3

You currently have BIOS "N78 Ver. 01.45". A newer BIOS "1.51" can be downloaded from [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-probook-450-g3-notebook-pc/7834555).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Note: This may, or may not, solve your halting problem. Try it and report back.

**Wayland**

Temporarily try this...

At the login screen, select your username, then click on the cogwheel icon, and select "Ubuntu under Wayland", then enter your password to continue logging in. Try running with Wayland and report back.

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Touchpad**

If you're not scared to open the laptop, and have a little technical skill, then do this... **or use a service technician**... find the ribbon cable that connects the trackpad to the motherboard. **CAREFULLY** unlock the cable latch on the motherboard and re-seat the ribbon cable. Some cable latches flip up, and some slide open. Be forewarned, if you break this latch, your laptop will require service. Report back.

Comment: thanks! I updated BIOS. I forgot to mention that I did this in summer, so very likely it won't help.

Comment: @OlenaStotska Good job! Try Wayland and memtest. Report back.

Comment: memtest done. wayland is in progress

Comment: @OlenaStotska Good job! Please do keep me posted.

Comment: system just crashed with wayland. I'll add the logs before crash to gist: https://gist.github.com/Olena-Stotska/341a3ffe91529bc1c20ae5396d9135c3#file-21-02-2021-syslog-wayland

Comment: @OlenaStotska Running with Wayland eliminated a lot of X11/XORG stuff. syslog snippets aren't giving me a whole lot of clues. /var/crash has nothing. You may have a hardware problem. Does HP have any built-in hardware diagnostics? Upload a complete syslog that includes the time frame for when you had a halt/crash, to paste.ubuntu.com, and give me the URL, and I'll take a long look for you. In your BIOS, choose "Reset to factory defaults" and see if that has any effect. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: fstab - https://gist.github.com/Olena-Stotska/341a3ffe91529bc1c20ae5396d9135c3#file-fstab . There are memory and hard drive tests which I can before boot. I've already done this before and everything was fine.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WkwnKcbQfV/ there are actually 2 entries in /var/crash . the last one happened 10 minutes before halt when running in wayland

Comment: This is the log for the last 30 minutes before crash with wayland: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5HFW3rFHxX/ 
Thanks for taking time looking at this! I'll try to reset bios to defaults

Comment: This is logs for the last hour when running on X11: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cJRfcJNfGt/

Comment: @OlenaStotska I've reviewed the logs. I do see a couple of segfaults (segmentation faults)... but nothing specific to nailing down a real suspect. You've got a tough one here! In desperation... boot to a Ubuntu Live USB in "Try Ubuntu" mode, and see if you still have the problem. BTW... I've been very impressed with your computer smarts!!

Comment: thanks :) do you have any guesses what can be wrong? I read on the internet that in case of syslog crashes (`^@` symbols) it's either temperature or power issues. What do you think?

Comment: @OlenaStotska You've checked for temp issues. Power... now there's something I hadn't considered... does your laptop have an internal non-removable battery? Try this... shutdown the laptop, and hold down the power key for about 20 seconds. This will reset the power manager. See if things improve. Also... did you try the Live USB that I suggested? That would eliminate a software problem.